# Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I looked at previous stack questions, but I am still lost. Help?

Here is the code in question:

```
  float dotproduct(int x[], int y[], int len){

    int output = 0;

    int* x1 = x;
    int* x2 = y;

    asm(
        ".loop: \n \t"

        "mov        %1,  %%rax \n\t"
        "imul       %2, %%rax \n\t"
        "add        %%rax, %%rbx \n\t"

        "add    $8, %1 \n\t"
        "add    $8, %2 \n\t"
        "dec    %3 \n\t"

        "jnz .loop \n\t"

        "movl %%ebx, %0 \n\t"
        :"=g" (output)
        :"g" (x1), "g" (x2), "g" (len)
        :"rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
    );

    return output;
}
```

Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction

[image: Linux terminal screenshot]

Comment: `%1, %2, %3` could all be memory operands (something like `-12(%rbp)`) and something like `add $8, -12(%rbp)` is ambiguous as the assembler doesn't know whether to add a byte, word, dword or qword.  Since `x1` is an `int *`, you presumably want a qword, so `addq`.

Comment: But there are a lot of other problems with this code.  You modify all of `%1, %2, %3` which are supposed to be input operands.  You multiply `%rax` by the pointer `x2` instead of what it points to.  You clobber `rcx` though you never use it.  You have a named label in the asm, which will be bad if your function is inlined.

Comment: In addition to the good points Nate mentioned, dotproduct is supposed to return a float, but `output` is an int.  And you should probably take a moment to consider why you want to write this in inline asm.  It *really hard* to get inline asm right.  And in this case, the C compiler can generate much better code.

Comment: This is x86-64 so you have SSE2, and should be using it (`cvtdq2ps` / `mulps` / `addps`) for an int->float dot product, unless you expect `len` to be typically < 4.  And BTW, besides the other numerous problems, it looks like you read RBX without having written it, in `add        %%rax, %%rbx` on the first iteration.  Just use a `"+r"` output with a variable you already initialized to zero.  (Or throw out the whole thing because you need to return a float, and the implication is that you should convert *before* multiply so you can avoid integer overflow. )